# Android Tabbar on every activity gives java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, tabs, stack-overflow

My Problem is, I have multiple activities under a single tab of TabActivity but the problem is if i am move from one activity to another activity more than three time at that time the "java.lang.StackOverflowError"  is occurred, sorry for my bad English communication.

Any help would be appreciated.

My Code is:-

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends ActivityGroup implements
        OnClickListener {

    Button mBtnAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
        mBtnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnAddManageAccount);
        mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == mBtnAdd) {
            Intent mInSecond = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            replaceContentView("SecondActivity", mInSecond);
        }
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActivityGroup implements
        OnClickListener {

    Button mBtnBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
        mBtnBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mBtnBackNewCustomer);
        mBtnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v==mBtnBack){
            Intent mInBack = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    FirstActivity.class);
            replaceContentView("FirstActivity", mInBack);
        }
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Error Logcat:-

```
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1409)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
07-19 11:02:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  a
```

Comment: I am surprised that "How you have managed Activities under a single tab"? Because you call every time CLEAR_TOP inside ReplaceContentView() method./

Comment: @PareshMayani so please tell me what is the solution?

Comment: Don't you preserve the Stack? I mean Push/Pop when start/stop activity?

Comment: @PareshMayani is there any example or link, if yes then please give me or give me solution in detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
public class ActivityStack extends ActivityGroup {

  private Stack<String> stack;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (stack == null) stack = new Stack<String>();
    //start default activity
    push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, FirstStackActivity.class));
  }

  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    pop();
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    pop();
  }


  public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
      stack.push(id);
      setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
  }

  public void pop() {
    if (stack.size() == 1) finish();
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
    if (stack.size() > 0) {
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
    }
  }
}
```

Launch tab

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId")
spec.setContent(intent);
```

Call next activity

```
public class FirstStackActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setClass(getParent(), SecondStackActivity .class);
          ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
          activityStack.push("SecondStackActivity", intent);


      }
    });
    setContentView(textView);
  }
}
```

Call next again

```
public class SecondStackActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setClass(getParent(), ThirdStackActivity .class);
          ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
          activityStack.push("ThirdStackActivity", intent);


      }
    });
    setContentView(textView);
  }
}
```

Comment: How to call FirstActivity again from SecondActivity?

Answer (score 2):

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is actually deprecated. 
You should be using Fragments instead. This will help managing your memory which will avoid your stack overflow error.

Basically your can either declare your fragments in the XML like the first item, you give them a place holder, like the second item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the first fragment will automatically inflate and display. However the @id/fragmentContainer will need to be inflated since we only stubbed it out.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

To create a fragment, just extend Fragment (Also make sure the Activity holding the fragment extends FragmentActivity). And then make sure you are creating and returning a View to display, similar to how you create and return a View for a ListView row.

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment_layout);

            /* All your find view by id's */
            return view;
    }
}
```

More information can be found here
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: But how to use fragment with tab, do u have any example link for that?

Comment: just updated with sample code and links. Hope it helps :) Note that you can use the compatibility library to back port fragments to Android 2.1. Don't forget to upvote if it helps and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `FirstActivity` should extend from the `ActivityGroup`, the rest should be extending `Activity` class like your `SecondActivity` and so on. Do not launch the `FirstActivity` from `SecondActivity`.

More detail in this tutorials:

http://www.gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i have more than 2 activities under one tab and your solution link give me same error.